# snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates creating a blank image

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to create some composite UIImage objects with this code:

```
someImageView.image = [ImageMaker coolImage];
```

ImageMaker:

```
- (UIImage*)coolImage {
    UIView *composite = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coolImage"]]; //This is a valid image - can be viewed when debugger stops here
    [composite addSubview:imgView];

    UIView *snapshotView = [composite snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
//at this point snapshotView is just a blank image
    UIImage *img = [self imageFromView:snapshotView];
    return img;

}

- (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

I just get back a blank black image. How can I fix?

Answer (score 8):

Supplying `YES` for `-snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` means it needs a trip back to the runloop to actually draw the image. If you supply `NO`, it will try immediately, but if your view is off screen or otherwise hasn't yet drawn to the screen, the snapshot will be empty.

To reliably get an image:

```
- (void)withCoolImage:(void (^)(UIImage *))block {
    UIView *composite = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coolImage"]]; //This is a valid image - can be viewed when debugger stops here
    [composite addSubview:imgView];

    UIView *snapshotView = [composite snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];

    // give it a chance to update the screen…
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        // … and now it'll be a valid snapshot in here
        if(block)
        {
            block([self imageFromView:snapshotView]);
        }
    });
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
[someObject withCoolImage:^(UIImage *image){
    [self doSomethingWithImage:image];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

The snapshotted view has to be drawn to the screen for a snapshot view to not be blank. In your case, the composite view must have a superview for drawing to work.

However, you should not be using the snapshotting API for this kind of action. It is very inefficient to create a view hierarchy for the sole purpose of creating an image. Instead, use the Core Graphics API's to setup a bitmap image context, perform drawing and get back the result using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's only rendering a black rectangle is because you're drawing the view hierarchy of the snapshot view, which is non-existent.

To make it work, you should pass `composite` as the parameter like so:

```
- (UIImage*)coolImage {
    UIView *composite = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coolImage"]]

    [composite addSubview:imgView];

    UIImage *img = [self imageFromView:composite];

    // Uncomment if you don't want composite to have imgView as its subview
    // [imgView removeFromSuperview];

    return img;

}
```

[image: Before]

[image: Result]