# snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates returns blank image on iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm doing a custom view controller transition in which the presented view controller, `detailVC`, is scaled down when dismissed.

The procedure I chose is the following:

1. snapshot `detailVC.view`, add it to the transition context's `containerView`
2. hide `detailVC.view`
3. scale down the snapshot.

Here's the code:

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let detailVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey) as? DetailViewController

    containerView.addSubview(detailVC.view)
    detailVC.view.frame = containerView.frame

    let detailVCSnapshot = detailVC.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
    containerView.addSubview(detailVCSnapshot)

    detailVC.view.hidden = true
    ...
}
```

Bizarrely, this works well on the iPad, but not on iPhone. On iPhone, `detailVCSnapshot` is completely transparent.

Other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203682/uiimage-from-a-uiview-created-with-snapshotviewafterscreenupdates), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913285/snapshotviewafterscreenupdates-creating-a-blank-image)) recommend ensuring that the view has been drawn, but this is indeed the case as `detailVC` is the currently visible view controller!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround involving using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` on iPhone:

```
let detailVCSnapshot = isIphone ? UIImageView(image: detailVC.view.snapshotImage) : detailVC.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)

private extension UIView {
    var snapshotImage: UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0)
        layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Any explanations or alternatives would be welcome!

Comment: This solution is unfortunately incredibly slower if you have lots of CALayer elements rendering. The other solution is lightning fast but seems to only work on some devices, very strange!